# How can I make a fixed div JUMP when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, fixed

**UPDATE: This is essentially what I want, but the div fixed to the bottom - http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/wp-content/demos/jquery-scrolling-element/**

There are loads of tutorials and questions about trying to avoid this, which is annoying because this is all I'm seeing when I'm trying to find out how to make it happen.

Originally, I had a fixed div that stuck to the bottom of the screen when scrolling. But I want to make this more noticeable, by making it hang on to the position when scrolling, and then smoothly jumping back down to the bottom of the screen (or up, if scrolling up).

I found this code, which kind of did the right stuff, but it was acting strangely, by starting about 2000px below the page, and then increasing as scrolling down.

```
//run once
    var el=$('#scrolldiv');
    var originalelpos=el.offset().top; // take it where it originally is on the page

    //run on scroll
     $(window).scroll(function(){
        var el = $('#scrolldiv'); // important! (local)
        var elpos = el.offset().top; // take current situation
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var finaldestination = windowpos+originalelpos;
        el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination},500);
     });
```

By default, the CSS of the div is:

```
#footerBar {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    padding:1.25em 0;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:.99;
    border-top:3px solid #877874;
    background-color: #61504d;
    background-image: url(img/checkered-pattern.png);
    min-height:52px;
    box-shadow:0 0 1.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Can someone help with the JS code to make it stick to the bottom of the screen, but smoothly jump when the page is scrolled?

http://jsfiddle.net/t1dLyyg7/

UPDATE:

I've found some different code, which seems to be closer to what I want. However, it's jumping to the original position the div was when the page loads, and not fixed to the bottom of the screen.

I can't see how I can adjust the dynamic `bottom` value, to always keep to the bottom of the screen when scrolled...

http://jsfiddle.net/svoa7cts/

Comment: It would be handy if you could set a fiddle for this. Tricky to start looking at without the html.

Comment: @thecraighammond - I didn't really think it was needed, as I had explained quite well I thought. But link has been supplied.

Comment: @Lee If you want someone to help you with a problem that you have, always make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: What do you mean by `jump`. Goes up and down?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden - Yes. As in, it's fixed at the bottom, but when the page is scrolled, the div follows the scroll, and then smoothly jumps from where it is back to the fixed at the bottom position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the initial `bottom` CSS declaration, make it `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed` and run the below JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/svoa7cts/2/

```
var ScrollTimer;
function fireScroll() {
    var $scrollingDiv = $("#footerBar");
    $scrollingDiv.animate({"top": ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $scrollingDiv.outerHeight()) + "px"}, "slow" ); 
};

$(window).scroll(function(){
    ScrollTimer && clearTimeout(ScrollTimer);
    ScrollTimer = setTimeout(fireScroll, 100); // Make it only fire when you stop scrolling
});
fireScroll(); // fire immediately upon page load
```

You could even give it an initial value of `top:100%;` so it springs up from the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/svoa7cts/3/

Comment: This is why I don't like making JSFiddles - Your JSfiddle works, but on my site it doens't. It pushes the div way down past the body content, and when scrolling down pushes it even further.

Comment: That would depend where it is on your website, and upon whether any ancestors have `position:relative`. In my example it is being displayed relative to the document. If you have an ancestor with `position:relative;` it will be displaying relative to that.

Comment: @Lee Also don't blame JSFiddle if the code **you** put into it doesn't represent what's going on on **your** website ;).

Comment: No, what I was getting at is that essentially you'd need to pretty much re-type all of your website code to try to create a replicate environment. Which is just a mammoth task.

Comment: @Lee in some cases, yes. But required none-the-less. I have fallen foul of  it myself...

Comment: Brilliant, working fine now. Realised I hadn't closed a container div which was setting the parent div as relative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83516/discussion-between-lee-and-jamie-barker).